# What is the .NET 4.0 support lifecycle parent product?

Tags: .net-4.0, lifecycle

.NET support dates are now linked to the support lifecycle of the parent product "As a Component, .NET takes the exact same Support Lifecycle as the parent product.": 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/lifecycle/archive/2010/04/30/net-framework-3-5-sp1-and-later-now-supported-as-part-of-microsoft-windows.aspx

Based on the diagram on the following page I can see that .NET 3.5 is linked to Windows 7 and .NET 4.5 to Windows 8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx

However .NET 4.0 (based on the information at that link) isn't included on any client or server OS, so I'm confused as to what the end of support date is for it.

In my case, I've chosen to install .NET 4.0 onto a Windows 2008 server, but it didn't come preinstalled on that server, and can presumably run on Windows 2012, so I'm getting pretty lost as to what the official end of support date is for this.

Comment: Windows 7.5, I guess.  If you worry about this then why don't you just install 4.5 instead.

Comment: problem is my client have some large apps, some of which are already on 4.0.  They're concerned about effort to regression test apps that then move to 4.5 and want to know the supported dates to help inform their thinking

Comment: You'll need to get this information from the horse's mouth if you want it to be authoritative enough to convince a client.  Call Microsoft Support.

Comment: Fair enough.  Given their announcement stated that "This servicing story led to some customer confusion and we recognized a need to provide greater clarity around the Support Lifecycle of the .NET Framework... To simplify this..." this might have been easily available information, but perhaps not! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net%20framework), not all versions have a parent product and .net 4.0 Extended support ends 12/01/2016.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a very recent change / clarification; looks like I need to talk to my client about upgrading to .NET 4.5.2...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [that](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net%20framework) page, Framework .Net 4.0 Extended support ends January 12, 2016.